# float:right using css - There must be an easy way to do this

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I have some text I want to display with a "V" after it and floated to the right. The text is a voltage (hence the V). It has an `id` and is calculated with JavaScript.

I'm sure there is a neat way of doing this, but I'm inexperienced and overcomplicating things and not getting anywhere!

I tried this:

```
<h3><span id="voltsSensor2"; style="float:right" >2.99</span>V</h3>
```

But because the V is outside the span it stays left.

I have also tried making the h3 tag all float left in css but for some reason it puts the text outside of the div area which is a box with a border as defined in my css as in this example:

```
<div class="ex">
    <h1 id = nameS1>Sensor 2</h1>
    <h2>Temperature</h2>
    <h3><span id="tempSensor2">18.5</span>&#176C</h3>

    <div style="width:255px; height:13px; background-color:#ddd;">
        <div id ="barTempS2" style="width:60px; height:13px; background-color:#366; border-right:1px white solid;"></div>
    </div>

    <h2>Humidity</h2>
    <h3><span id="humSensor2">55.0</span>%RH</h3>

    <div style="width:255px; height:13px; background-color:#ddd;">
        <div id ="barHumS2" style="width:140px; height:13px; background-color:#366"></div>
    </div>

    <h4><span id="voltsSensor1">2.99</span>V</h4>
    <img src="images/greyCornerRhb.png" width="12" height="12" alt="Sensor Name"; style="float:right">
</div>
```

I'm sure there is a much easier way. I would be grateful for some help.

Comment: Why is the V outside the span? Why not add a span? For that matter, why float it? What is wrong with `text-align`?

Answer (score 3):

You should just use a `text-align: right;` on the parent element and lose the `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<h3 style="float:right"><span id="voltsSensor2">2.99</span>V</h3>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BJPUv/

The `clear:both` div will allow for the height of the floated elements so they dont float out of the div.

Comment: Wow, have never heard of clear:both, not surprising really. It worked perfectly. Thanks

Comment: It seems to have given me a little bit of extra padding under the text, I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Two things you could very easily do. Either stick the V in its own span and specify position:relative and float:right for both spans. Or just stick the V in the span of the number. You could append the "V" in the js code after you have calculated the value.